# Alter CSS Grid to accomodate an element expanding

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

The code in the following snippet renders a resonsive grid, that expands an element that is clicked.

```js
const Demo = () => {

  const Item = ({content}) => {

    const [expanded, setExpanded] = React.useState(false);

    return (<div className = {
        expanded ? "expanded" : "item"
      }
      onClick = {
        () => setExpanded(!expanded)
      }>
        {content}
      </div>)
  }

  return (<div className = "grid" >
      <Item content = "Item 1" / >
      <Item content = "Item 2" / >
      <Item content = "Item 3" / >
      <Item content = "Item 4" / >
      <Item content = "Item 5" / >
      <Item content = "Item 6" / >
    </div>)
}

ReactDOM.render( < Demo / > , document.querySelector("#app"))
```

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  gap: 1rem;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(min(200px, 100%), 1fr));
}

.item {
  display: flex;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.expanded {
  display: flex;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="app" />
```

When clicking on e.g. *Item 2*, the grid looks as follows:

[image: Grid after clicking Item 2]

However, in this case, I would like the grid to look like:

[image: Expected grid after clicking Item 2]

How would I go about fixing this? The solution does not have to use the a CSS Grid. However, the responsive width of the elements, and the responsive number of rows and columns must be maintained.

Comment: What if an item becomes really big – is it OK to push other items to other columns for better balancing?

Comment: @Thomas Yes, that would be fine as well!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for dense grid layout then on grid container you need mention that you need [dense auto flow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-auto-flow) in rows:

```
.grid {
  ...
  grid-auto-flow: row dense;
}
```

To properly increase the items' height, increase row span as well:

```css
.expanded {
  height: 200px;
  grid-row: span 2;  /* <--- */
}
```

```js
const Demo = () => {
    const Item = ({content}) => {
        const [expanded, setExpanded] = React.useState(false);
        return ( < div className = {            expanded ? "expanded" : "item" }
          onClick = { () => setExpanded(!expanded)
          } > { content} </div>) }

        return ( < div className = "grid" >
          <Item content = "Item 1" / >
          <Item content = "Item 2" / >
          <Item content = "Item 3" / >
          <Item content = "Item 4" / >
          <Item content = "Item 5" / >
          <Item content = "Item 6" / >
          </div>)
        }
        ReactDOM.render( < Demo / > , document.querySelector("#app"))
```

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  gap: 1rem;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(min(200px, 100%), 1fr));

  /* use dense layout */
  grid-auto-flow: row dense;
}

.item {
  display: flex;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.expanded {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid black;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;

  height: calc(200px + 1rem);
  /* need to increase row span also */
  grid-row: span 2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="app" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's really possible to do what do you want to do only with **Grid** property.

Because we have two main grid size property: ***grid-template-rows*** and ***grid-template-columns***.

And the third one: ***grid-template-columns***, you can make different sizes for *rows* and *columns*.

But the main problem is if you get bigger than the column height, you will push everyone around.

This is an example using the method I mentioned above:

```css
html, body {
    height: 100vh;
}

.grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas: "a b c";
    grid-template-areas: "a b c" "a b c";
    height: 100vh;
}

.item {
    background-color: blueviolet;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    border: solid;
}

.item:hover {
    height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="grid">
        <span class="item">1</span>
        <span class="item">2</span>
        <span class="item">3</span>
        <span class="item">4</span>
        <span class="item">5</span>
        <span class="item">6</span>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

So to resolve your problem, use **Flex** property, you can do a **grid with 3 columns** and every column has its flex property.

Like that:

```css
html, body {
    height: 100vh;
}

.grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: auto;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, auto);
    height: 100vh;
}

.column-items {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color: blueviolet;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    height: fit-content;
    width: 100px;
}

.item {
    border: solid;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}

.item:hover {
    height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="grid">
        <div class="column-items">
            <span class="item">1</span>
            <span class="item">2</span>
        </div>

        <div class="column-items">
            <span class="item">3</span>
            <span class="item">4</span>
        </div>

        <div class="column-items">
            <span class="item">5</span>
            <span class="item">6</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```